# Looking for a simple executable example of offline map in Xamarin android

Tags: android, dictionary, xamarin.android

I just want to find the easiest way to insert offline maps in Xamarin android app and I tried Carto based on Nutiteq SDK and it requires me to put the .mbtiles files into the project asset folder. I tried to put a .mbtiles into the folder but it failed to display the street lines and names of places. Does anyone have some experience with offline maps? Thanks